# create one pdf from multiple ppt files

Tags: pdf, adobe, powerpoint

Someone knows how can I create one pdf file from multiple ppt files ?
Whether it to write script or computer program. However if it can be done with some program it will be the best.

I searched the web for something like this but I didn't get any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the PPT/PPTX files to PDF and then join those converted PDF files into a single PDF using either .NET or Java, you may try Aspose.Slides and Aspose.Pdf.Kit components.

[Aspose.Slides](http://www.aspose.com/categories/product-family-packs/aspose.slides-product-family/default.aspx) allows you to convert the PPT/PPTX files to PDF and [Aspose.Pdf.kit](http://www.aspose.com/categories/product-family-packs/aspose.pdf.kit-product-family/default.aspx) allows you to join the PDF files into a single PDF. Please see if this solution can work for your scenario.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.